# How to make a video chat on Windows 8 through the MSN network?

Tags: windows-8, windows-live-messenger

I searched in a lot of ways, but it looks like there isn't a button to initiate a video chat on the MSN network on windows 8.
I couldn't even accept incoming video calls.
The same with the new Skype (using MSN network)

The feature is being phased away hence available only in older clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the recent announcements, the phasing out of Windows Live Messenger, and the unification of Windows Live Accounts in Skype, it's clear that Microsoft purposely didn't include video chat through the MSN network in Windows 8: it has to be done via Skype.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the  Camfrog Video Chat 6.1.146 it an alernate way and also support windows 8
Link:-http://www.freenew.net/windows/camfrog-video-chat-6-1-146/68851.htm